# 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'raw_query'

Tags: django, tastypie, django-nonrel

nonrel(Mongodb) with tastypie.I have created one resource class which return  selected  auth_user from the database.Because of some reasons I did change **_id** field type from **ObjectId** to **Int64**.I used raw_query() for accessing desired auth_user but it doesn't seems to work.Can anyone suggest me what should I do to make raw_query() work for UserModel.

**Here is my tastypie resource:**

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:

        queryset=User.objects.raw_query({'_id':5})
        resource_name="user"
        fields=["username","first_name","last_name"]
        include_resource_uri=False
        allowed_methods=["get"]
```

**output**:

```
'UserManager' object has no attribute 'raw_query'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Tastypie at all. Are you sure you need a raw query, or is the above just an example?

By looking at the [docs](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/lowerlevel.html) you should be able to do the following:

```
from django_mongodb_engine.contrib import MongoDBManager

class User(models.Model):
    mongo_manager = MongoDBManager()
```

Then you should be able to use it as you do above, i.e:

```
queryset=User.mongo_manager.raw_query({'_id':5})
```

Comment: still got the same error.The question was how can I change manger for django's UserModel?

Comment: Try replacing `objects` with something else if you don't need anything in the `UserManager`

Comment: thank you dan for ur suggestion..I have found the solution and answered my own question:)

Answer (score 0):

I myself workaround to this problem and for the sake of others help I am answering my own question.Hope this will help someone.

This solution is to create a proxy model.By declaring proxy models we can do opertions on parent model and even can modify manager.

**proxy model:**

```
class UserClass(User):
    objects = MongoDBManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
```

**Resource:**
    class UserResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:

```
        queryset=UserClass.objects.raw_query({'_id':5})
        resource_name="user"
        fields=["username","first_name","last_name"]
        include_resource_uri=False
        allowed_methods=["get"]
```